# Remove custom taxonomy column from my custom post type columns

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, columns

I am using wp 3.5 i have a custom post `(sp_product)` and also i have custom taxonomy. I want to remove that custom taxonomy filter column but i don't want to make `'show_admin_column' => false`.

I wanna unset from `$columns['']` .

How should i do that ? i also want to add some css/js when it will show in column and top select menu. (showing in this image like)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function wpse_80027_manage_columns($columns) {
    // remove taxonomy column
    unset($columns['taxonomy-YOUR_TAXONOMY_NAME']); // prepend taxonomy name with 'taxonomy-'
    // add your custom column
    $columns['CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME'] = __('Column Name');
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-sp_product_columns', 'wpse_80027_manage_columns');


function wpse_80027_add_img_column($name) {
    if('CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME' == $name) {
        // echo your image in 'CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME' column
        echo '<img src="image-name.png />';
    }
}
add_action('manage_sp_product_posts_custom_column', 'wpse_80027_add_img_column');
```

Comment: This answer is actually partially incorrect. The correct context is unset($columns['taxonomy-{taxonomy_name_here}']);

Just using the taxonomy name itself in the unset will not work.

Comment: @HybridWebDev, you are perfectly right! Thank you for making a good point! My apologies, the answer is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'unregister_taxonomy');
function unregister_taxonomy(){
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $taxonomy = 'taxonomy_to_remove';
    if ( taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy))
        unset( $wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy]);
}
```

```
<php


function remove_taxonomy($taxonomy) {
    if (!$taxonomy->_builtin) {
        global $wp_taxonomies;
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); 
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            wp_delete_term( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );
        }
        unset($wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy]);
    }
}

function deactivate_custom_taxes() {
    remove_taxonomy('post_tag');  // this will fail silently
    // do we need to flush the rewrite rules? 
    $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->flush_rules();
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_custom_taxes' );
>
```

Please check this and let me know ....

Comment: sorry to say i can't understand you answer . But i find its solution. and also thank you too.